# cakephp 1.3 : getting warning: strtotime() on console

Tags: php, cakephp-1.3

I am trying to create a controller in cakephp using console. But when I try to do so,I am getting a warning on my console window as follows

How can i  fix this issue ?

> C:\xampp\htdocs\cake\apressblog\app>cake
>
> Warning: strtotime(): It is not safe
>   to rely on the system's timezone
>   settings. You are *required* to use
>   the date.timezone setting or the
>   date_default_timezone
>   _set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still
>   getting  this warning, you most likely
>   misspelled the timezone identifier. We
>   selected ' Asia/Calcutta' for '5.5/no
>   DST' instead in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\cake\apressblog\cake\
>   libs\cache.php on line 570
>
> Warning: strtotime(): It is not safe
>   to rely on the system's timezone
>   settings. You are *required* to use
>   the date.timezone setting or the
>   date_default_timezone
>   _set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still
>   getting  this warning, you most likely
>   misspelled the timezone identifier. We
>   selected ' Asia/Calcutta' for '5.5/no
>   DST' instead in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\cake\apressblog\cake\
>   libs\cache.php on line 570 ♀ Welcome
>   to CakePHP v1.3.4 Console
>   --------------------------------------------------------------- Current Paths:  -app: app  -working:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\cake\apressblog\app 
>   -root: C:\xampp\htdocs\cake\apressblog  -core: C:\xampp\htdocs\cake\apressblog
>
> Changing Paths: your working path
>   should be the same as your application
>   path to change your path use the
>   '-app' param. Example: -app
>   relative/path/to/myapp or -app
>   /absolute/path/to/myapp
>
> Available Shells:  acl [CORE]
>   i18n [CORE]
>
> api [CORE]
>   schema [CORE]
>
> bake [CORE]
>   testsuite [CORE]
>
> console [CORE]
>
> To run a command, type 'cake
>   shell_name [args]' To get help on a
>   specific command, type 'cake
>   shell_name help'
>
> C:\xampp\htdocs\cake\apressblog\app>

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Your Cake application tries to use a different time zone as your WAMP/PHP

change timezone in `/cake/console/cake.php`
or
change date.timezone in `php.ini`